# Azure: Is possible to do ARM Templates for Marketplace Tomcat8?

Tags: java, azure, tomcat, azure-resource-manager

I've created a parametrized ARM Template for being able to create my resource group structure over three different environments ("development", "acceptance" and "production").

I want to run Java applications in Tomcat (but having full control of the Tomcat (adding libs, editing server.xml, tomcat-users.xml, etc).

For that I want to use Marketplace Tomcat8 that gives full ftp access to the Tomcat structure/configuration.

So the question is: It's possible to create a Marketplace Tomcat8 using ARM Templates?

Creating a default Web App with application settings "javaVersion": "1.8", "javaContainer": "Tomcat", "javaContainerVersion": "8.0", I already done it, but it's not enough.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: What errors / issues are you seeing? what does 'its not enough' mean?

Comment: I configure the application settings as described in "http://donovanbrown.com/post/2016/01/24/Provisioning-a-Java-8-Tomcat-web-app-in-Azure-using-an-ARM-Template".

Answer (score 0):

I check the RM REST API calls used when creating a Marketplace Tomcat8 in azure portal and discovered that the ARM Template used is: https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/TomcatTemplate

This templates gets tomcat8 from a repo. So in my tomcat8app "resources" field I just added:

```
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "web",
      "type": "sourcecontrols",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('my_tomcat8app_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "RepoUrl": "[variables('tomcat8_repoUrl')]",
        "branch": "[variables('tomcat8_branch')]",
        "IsManualIntegration": true
      }
    }
```

with variables:

"tomcat8_repoUrl": "https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/TomcatTemplate",
"tomcat8_branch": "master"

And it's done! :)